# Android app doesn't load up on the emulator

Tags: android, emulation

My app has no errors in it however when i come to run it on the emulator then the emulator runs but doesn't show my app and comes up with this

error message -

> [2013-03-15 09:47:57 - Writees] No Launcher activity found!
>   [2013-03-15 09:47:57 - Writees] The launch will only sync the
>   application package on the device!

This is my manifest -

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> ```
>    android:allowBackup = "True">
>        <activity
>            android:name="com.example.writees.LoginActivity"
>            android:label="@string/app_name" >
>            <intent-filter>
>                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                <intent-filter>
>                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>                </intent-filter>
>            </intent-filter>
>        </activity>
>        <!-- dashboard Activity  -->
>        <activity
>            android:name="com.example.writees.DashboardActivity"
>            android:label="dashboard" >
>        </activity>
>
>        <!-- main Activity -->
>        <activity
>            android:name="com.example.writees.MainActivity"
>            android:label="main" >
>        </activity>
>
>        <!-- Register Activity -->
>        <activity
>            android:name="com.example.writees.RegisterActivity"
>            android:label="Register New Account" >
>        </activity>
>
>        <!-- Book Activity -->
>        <activity
>            android:name="com.example.writees.BookActivity"
>            android:label="book" >
>        </activity>
> ```
>
> />

Answer (score 1):

> No Launcher activity found!

You did not set any activity as a Launcher in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make any one activity that you want to launch first as Launcher activity.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```